# Read only service : javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a service that reads data from database. After reading there is a flush which causes the exception mentioned in the title. Below is the sequence of statements

```
    ManagerFactory factory = new ManagerFactory();
    EntityManager manager = factory.getManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = manager.getTransaction();

    Query query = manager.createQuery("select personRoleJPA from personRoleJPA");
    personRoleJPA = (PersonRoleJPA) query.getSingleResult();

    if (manager.isOpen()) {
       manager.flush();
    }
    if (manager.isOpen()) {
       manager.close();
       manager = null;
    }
    if (transaction.isActive()) {
     transaction.commit();
   }
```

I suspect the exception is because I did not begin the transaction. **My question is do you really need to flush & commit when you are not doing any writes ?**

Comment: No it is not required to flush and commit when you are not writing anything

Comment: Remove all the lines related to the transaction and you will get rid of the problem

Comment: @ Hussein Zawawi : You mean I need not even create a transaction ' EntityTransaction transaction = manager.getTransaction();' ?

Comment: @ Hussein Zawawi : so only closing the manager is enough ?  *if (manager.isOpen()) {
       manager.close();
       manager = null;
    }*

Answer (score 1):

Remove everything related to transaction since you dont need an active transaction to retrieve data:

```
ManagerFactory factory = new ManagerFactory();
    EntityManager manager = factory.getManager();

    Query query = manager.createQuery("select personRoleJPA from personRoleJPA");
    personRoleJPA = (PersonRoleJPA) query.getSingleResult();

    if (manager.isOpen()) {
       manager.flush();
    }
    if (manager.isOpen()) {
       manager.close();
       manager = null;
    }
```

Comment: Is it required to begin transaction when I am not writing anything?

Comment: yes , you can not call commit on an inactive Transaction , when you call Transaction.begin() , transaction gets active .@Sandra

Answer (score 0):

About `flush()` method you can read from documentation:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29
If you read anything from database you do not need `transaction.commit()`.`commit()` using for saving changes after sql statement executed but in select statement you do not need `commit`.Default in `JDBC` commit is auto-commit mode.In hibernate configuration file you can change this settings.The best practice is disabling auto-commit mode.
About `commit()` you can also read from:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html